# Python Getting date online?

Tags: python

How can I get the current date, month & year online using Python? By this I mean, rather than getting it from the computer's date-visit a website and get it, so it doesn't rely on the computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "online"?

Comment: Is there any code you've tried that has failed? An error message perhaps>? A line in the python documentation that doesn't make sense? An example of what you're trying to do that helps to explain the use of the word "online"? We'll need additional details on the problem in order to help you.

Comment: Please be nice to NTP servers. They are often provided as a public service, and the people running them have to put up with a lot of crap as it is.

Comment: I should point out that http://just-the-time.appspot.com OTOH should be game for heavy-ish load -- Google says it provides enough free resources for 5 millions pageviews/month or so (and just-the-time is definitely way more lightweight per pageview than just about any web app I can think of;-). Hmmm, let me opensource it so people can easily run their own instances...

Comment: OK, the (trivial) sources are now available at http://code.google.com/p/just-the-time/ so anybody can run their own instance, etc etc.

Answer (score 40):

So thinking about the "would be so trivial" part I went ahead and just made [a google app engine web app](http://just-the-time.appspot.com/) -- when you visit it, it returns a simple response claiming to be HTML but actually just a string such as `2009-05-26 02:01:12 UTC\n`. Any feature requests?-)

Usage example with Python's urllib module:

Python 2.7

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> res = urlopen('http://just-the-time.appspot.com/')
>>> time_str = res.read().strip()
>>> time_str
'2017-07-28 04:55:48'
```

Python 3.x+

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> res = urlopen('http://just-the-time.appspot.com/')
>>> result = res.read().strip()
>>> result
b'2017-07-28 04:53:46'
>>> result_str = result.decode('utf-8')
>>> result_str
'2017-07-28 04:53:46'
```

Comment: Taking your request at face value...how about seconds since the epoch? :)

Comment: OK, second version deployed: now takes an optional ?f=... query parameter that lets you specify the strftime format, with an extension that %t expands to seconds-since-the-epoch. So for example, http://just-the-time.appspot.com/?f=%Y%m%d,%20seconds%20since%20the%20epoch:%20%t now returns as the response's body "20090526, seconds since the epoch: 1243305356.12".

Other feature requests...?

Comment: Is there any chance you can let me have the code for that-ideally I'm looking for it in the form May 26, 2009 but I'm sure I can have a play around! Very clever though!

Comment: sure, I put all the code up (there ain't much to it!-) a few minutes ago at http://code.google.com/p/just-the-time/ .

Comment: btw, for 'May 26, 2009' just visit http://just-the-time.appspot.com/?f=%b%20%d,%20%Y ...

Comment: Any specific reason for appending `\n`?

Comment: @AlexMartelli is this project still active to contribute to?

Comment: Link no longer appears to be active.

Comment: @chepner, assuming you mean the source, I just downloaded the source from https://code.google.com/archive/p/just-the-time/source/default/source to confirm that it IS perfectly active. Of course, you need an installation of the good old https://subversion.apache.org/ to take full advantage of the source-control aspects of the repo, but that's unlikely to matter, just use the files that live in just-the-time/trunk after you download and unpack the zipfile. The appengine link currently gives a 500 HTTP error, I'll investigate when I have time, but putting up a new appengine app is easy!

Comment: ...AND I've now fixed the .appspot.com deployment -- problem was just that the CC I had on the GCP account on which this app depended had expired long ago.

Comment: ...however, formatting of "seconds since the epoch" NOT working currently with the ?f=... query string -- I'll need to work on that, but no spare time right now! Stay tuned...

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use NTP, but rather want to stick with HTTP, you could `urllib.urlget("http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime")` and parse the results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error xmlns="urn:yahoo:api">
        The following errors were detected:
        <Message>Appid missing or other error </Message>
</Error>
<!-- p6.ydn.sp1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Mon May 25 18:42:11 PDT 2009 -->
```

Note that the datetime (in PDT) is in the final comment (the error message is due to lack of APP ID). There probably are more suitable web services to get the current date and time in HTTP (without requiring registration &c), since e.g. making such a service freely available on Google App Engine would be so trivial, but I don't know of one offhand.

Comment: So rather than abusing Yahoo's courtesy please try my brand-new GAE app at http://just-the-time.appspot.com/ and let me know what you think - feature requests accepted (took me 10 minutes to code, deploy and test, so a few more minutes won't hurt;-). "Will work for SO upvotes"...?-)

Answer (score 5):

For this NTP server can be used.

```
import ntplib
import datetime, time
print('Make sure you have an internet connection.')

try:

    client = ntplib.NTPClient()
    response = client.request('pool.ntp.org')
    Internet_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time)  
    print('\n')
    print('Internet date and time as reported by NTP server: ',Internet_date_and_time)


except OSError:

    print('\n')
    print('Internet date and time could not be reported by server.')
    print('There is not internet connection.')
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to utilise an online time string, e.g. derived from an online service (http://just-the-time.appspot.com/), it can be read and converted into a datetime.datetime format using urllib2 and datetime.datetime:

```
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime
def getOnlineUTCTime():
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen("http://just-the-time.appspot.com/")
    internettime = webpage.read()
    OnlineUTCTime = datetime.strptime(internettime.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return OnlineUTCTime
```

or very compact (less good readable)

```
OnlineUTCTime=datetime.strptime(urllib2.urlopen("http://just-the-time.appspot.com/").read().strip(),
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

little exercise: 
Comparing your own UTC time with the online time:

```
print(datetime.utcnow() - getOnlineUTCTime())
# 0:00:00.118403
#if the difference is negatieve the result will be something like: -1 day, 23:59:59.033398
```

(bear in mind that processing time is included also)

Answer (score 1):

Goto `timezonedb.com` and create an account u will receive api key on the your email and use the api key in the following code

```
from urllib import request
from datetime import datetime
import json


def GetTime(zone):
    ApiKey="YOUR API KEY"
    webpage=request.urlopen("http://api.timezonedb.com/v2/get-time-zone?key=" +ApiKey + "&format=json&by=zone&zone="+zone)
    internettime = json.loads(webpage.read().decode("UTF-8"))
    OnlineTime = datetime.strptime(internettime["formatted"].strip(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return(OnlineTime)


print(GetTime("Asia/Kolkata"))   #you can pass any zone region name for ex : America/Chicago
```

Answer (score 1):

This works really well for me, no account required:

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime


def get_internet_datetime(time_zone: str = "etc/utc") -> datetime:
    """
    Get the current internet time from:
    'https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=etc/utc'
    """
    timeapi_url = "https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
    }
    params = {"timeZone": time_zone}

    dt = None
    try:
        request = requests.get(timeapi_url, headers=headers, params=params)
        r_dict = request.json()
        dt = datetime(
            year=r_dict["year"],
            month=r_dict["month"],
            day=r_dict["day"],
            hour=r_dict["hour"],
            minute=r_dict["minute"],
            second=r_dict["seconds"],
            microsecond=r_dict["milliSeconds"] * 1000,
        )
    except Exception:
        logger.exception("ERROR getting datetime from internet...")
        return None

    return dt
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a python module for hitting NIST online http://freshmeat.net/projects/mxdatetime.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean the NTP protocol? This project may help: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/0.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I made for myself. I was getting a problem in linux that the date and time changes each time I switch on my PC, so instead setting again and again as the internet requires proper date. I made this script which will be used by date command to set date and time automatically through an alias.

```
    import requests

    resp = requests.get('https://www.timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=etc/utc')
    resp = resp.text
    resp = str(resp)
    resp
    first = resp.find('"date":"')  + 8
    rp = ''
    for i in range(first , 145):
        rp = resp[i] + rp
    print(rp[::-1]+"\n")
    second = resp.find('"time":"')  + 8

    rp_2 = ''
    for i in range(second , 160):
        rp_2 = resp[i] + rp_2
    print(rp_2[::-1]+"\n")
```