# Easy way to get the correct time in python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm running some jobs on a cluster where the dates on each node are slightly off from one another. Is there an easy way to get the time from somewhere on the internet via python or do I need to have the sysadmin sync the times between the machines more frequently?

I'd like to put a time-stamp in the output from each job I launch, but obviously the accuracy of the python's `time.strftime()` etc are going to depend on the machine knowing the correct time. I'd love accuracy within a few seconds, but right now it's within minutes.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908550/python-getting-date-online

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ntplib for python. I've played around with it a bit and it seems pretty stable.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/

Comment: the link has expired. this is the updated one https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/

Answer (score 11):

I'm dealing with a standalone sensor device that runs Linux 2.6.33, Python 2.6.5, and unfortunately lacks a real-time clock but *does* have networking capabilities.  Additionally, the device uses BusyBox so it has a minimalized set of tool capabilities.

I created the script below that executes after the network is running to correct the system time.  My solution might not exactly address the original question (sounds like Noah is a user and not an admin on the system), but this question is what comes when searching for sync'ing system clock using Python via NTP.  I figure it might help others that land here.

Before you use the script, you'll need to install ntplib.  The download link and installation instructions are here:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/.

Copy the the contents of the code below to a file (I named mine "synctime.py").  Then, after the network is running, execute the script (e.g. "python synctime.py").  You will need to do this using elevated (root) privileges for this to work properly.

```
import time
import os

try:
    import ntplib
    client = ntplib.NTPClient()
    response = client.request('pool.ntp.org')
    os.system('date ' + time.strftime('%m%d%H%M%Y.%S',time.localtime(response.tx_time)))
except:
    print('Could not sync with time server.')

print('Done.')
```

Comment: Printing out the exception reveals "No response from pool.ntp.org."

Comment: I just tried the script as written and it worked fine for me.  Have you tried checking your connection back to pool.ntp.org?  For example, "traceroute -n pool.ntp.org" can be useful to troubleshoot issues.  Further, "host pool.ntp.org" may reveal what IP addresses are resolving for that domain name.  At the time of this writing, I see 4 entries.

Comment: If you see "No response from.." it's very likely you forgot to pip3 install ntplib. The failure that would be reported at "import ntplib" is trapped by the try, so you don't see it and assume the client.request() failed.

Comment: I was having the same problem. I just used `0.pool.ntp.org`. I read their website and learnt that they have 4 global servers starting from 0 to 3 similar to the above domain.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you should look into using something like [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) to keep the machines' time in sync with one another (and preferably, a global standard time source).

Answer (score 1):

Run "w32tm /resync" on cmd.

```
import os

os.system('w32tm /resync')
```

Answer (score 1):

-->Run "w32tm /resync" on cmd.

this dosnt not work in my case.

which work for me:

```
        client = ntplib.NTPClient()
        response = client.request('pool.ntp.org')
        t = datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time)
        time_ntp = t.strftime("%m %d %H:%M:%S %Y")#Mon Jul 05 13:58:39 2021
        print('NTP Time='+str(time_ntp))
        #os.system('w32tm /resync')
        os.system('date ' +  t.strftime("%x"))
        os.system('time ' +  t.strftime("%X"))
```

-praveen

Comment: what result did you get?  what did you expect?