# How to check time from internet using bash or python?

Tags: python, bash, time, ntp

This should be a very simple task, but after 2 hours of searching and reading documents I failed to find a way to check the date and time from the internet using bash or python without installing anything extra like ntplib.

I am basically looking for an equivalent of pythons now() or bash $ date, but using an NTP (or any other way) to get the correct date and time from the internet. All the methods I find (such as ntpd) are meant to correct the system time, which is not my purpose.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664295/ntp-client-in-python). It's fairly old, but I think it might still hold. It includes solutions that do not include the installation of extra modules.

Comment: @idjaw the solution on the link you posted does not work

Comment: I provided three different links with different answers in each. I have no idea which one you are referring to.

Comment: @tikkat also, notice that `ntplib` is a single file project - you can "install" it by copying `ntplib`; unless, of course, you can't obey the MIT license.

Answer (score 0):

[Easy way to get the correct time in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222951/easy-way-to-get-the-correct-time-in-python)

```
import time
import os

try:
    import ntplib
    client = ntplib.NTPClient()
    response = client.request('pool.ntp.org')
    os.system('date ' + time.strftime('%m%d%H%M%Y.%S',time.localtime(response.tx_time)))
except:
    print('Could not sync with time server.')

print('Done.')
```

Comment: This one works, but I am looking for a solution that does not require me to install anything like ntplib. Sorry, I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908550/python-getting-date-online there seem to be a lot of helpful implementations on this thread