# How to get correct date instead of system date in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I'm working on a project, there's one problem, I need to fetch a correct date. and I can also fetch date from web --> [Python Getting date online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908550/python-getting-date-online) , but the date will not be correct for every single person, Like if someone is living in USA so that's a problem, So how can I implement to fetch correct time for everyone.

**THANKS**

Comment: Is it necessary to get the date from online? If not you can use to get datetime using `datetime` module in `utc`

Comment: yeah because a certain task can be faked

Comment: The datetime returned from http://just-the-time.appspot.com/ is UTC, so for everybody, it will be same.

Comment: @Episi95 IDK It gave me wrong time :(

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
import datetime
import time

r = requests.get('http://just-the-time.appspot.com/')

utc_current_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(r.content.decode().strip(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(f'utc_current_time: {utc_current_time}')

utc_offset_in_seconds = time.timezone

if(utc_offset_in_seconds > 0):
    local_time = utc_current_time - datetime.timedelta(seconds=abs(time.timezone))
else:
    local_time = utc_current_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=abs(time.timezone))

print(f'local_time: {local_time}')
```

Comment: Whoa nice, When I changed my date intentionally then also it told me the correct date, Thanks dude, Really it means a lot to me

Comment: So does this means anybody will get correct date? pls  reply

Comment: The api `http://just-the-time.appspot.com/` gives datetimetime in `UTC`. I just added the `UTC` offset. So ideally everybody should get their local time.

Comment: If you change your system settings then there is no way. How do you suppose to detect if the very pc is incorrect?

Comment: You can get the utc offset from IP address but that can also be manipulated.

Comment: No bro, IDK but when I changed my timezone on my PC, the time changed but not the date, And I just need date to do my task! IDK how it works but it works!!!!!!! Thanks A LOT dude, and I am sorry for yesterday! Like yesterday I got wrong time and I freaked out I forgot that time doesn't matter I just need date for doing my task, So I removed your answer from accepted! I am really sorry for my rude behavior! Again thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah it can be manipulated as anyone can use VPN or something! Isn't it?

Comment: right, and the date also can change. Suppose the UTC offset is 6 hours ahead. Now somebody sitting in England on 15th Feb, 2021 at 7pm, then a person in india will be in 16th February.

Comment: So, sitting in india if I change my pc time as england, you can't say whether I am in india or england.

Comment: In this case people normally depend on third-party like cellular tower, ip address etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Tijuana')
now = datetime.now(tz)
```

Or you can use arrow https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
import arrow

arrow.now('America/New_York')
```

Comment: note `pytz` is becoming [outdated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/). with Python 3.9, you have `zoneinfo` in the standard lib, no need for third-party modules.

Comment: How to fetch all the timezones available in arrow

Comment: @UnknownBuddy179 
https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#id8
timezone names from tz database provided via dateutil package, note that abbreviations such as MST, PDT, BRST are unlikely to parse due to ambiguity. Use the full IANA zone name instead (Asia/Shanghai, Europe/London, America/Chicago etc).